# Cant show data on Ionic *ngfor

Tags: php, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello i have a problem returning data on html file using an Ionic app. I use an auth-service.ts provider to connect to database and the results are returning fine on console-> network-> XHR (friendsNewsFeed)

On ionic serve i am getting error 
trying to diff [object Object] only arrays and iterables are allowed

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-ngfor/121590

home.ts

```
      import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
      import { NavController, App, AlertController } from "ionic-angular";
      import { AuthService } from "../../providers/auth-service";
      import { Common } from "../../providers/common";
      import { Camera, CameraOptions } from "@ionic-native/camera";
      @Component({ selector: "page-home", templateUrl: "home.html" })


      export class HomePage {
public photos: any;
public base64Image: string;
public fileImage: string;
public userDetails: any;
public resposeData: any;
public dataSet: any;
public noRecords: boolean;
userPostData = {
    uid: "",
    token: "",
    created: "",
    message: ""
};
constructor(
    public authService: AuthService
) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    this.userDetails = data.userData;
    this.userPostData.uid = this.userDetails.uid;
    this.userPostData.token = this.userDetails.token;
    this.userPostData.created = "";
    this.noRecords = false
    this.getFeed();
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSet = [];
}   
getFeed() {
    this.common.presentLoading();
    this.authService.postData(this.userPostData, "userNewsFeed").then(
        result => {
            this.resposeData = result;
            if (this.resposeData) {
                this.common.closeLoading();
                this.dataSet = this.resposeData;
                console.log(this.dataSet);

            } else {
                console.log("No access");
            }
        },
        err => {
            //Connection failed message
        }
    );
}
```

home.html

```
       <ion-card *ngFor="let item of dataSet; let msgIndex = index">
      <ion-item>
      <ion-card-content>
      <p [innerHTML]="item.message | linky"></p>
      </ion-card-content>
      </ion-item>
      </ion-card>
```

auth-service.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

        let apiUrl = "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful1/api/";
        //let apiUrl = 'https://api.thewallscript.com/restful/';
        /*
          Generated class for the AuthService provider.

          See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
          for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
        */
        @Injectable()
        export class AuthService {

          constructor(public http: Http) {
            console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
          }

          postData(credentials, type){

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
              let headers = new Headers();
              this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
              subscribe(res =>{
                resolve(res.json());
              }, (err) =>{
                reject(err);
              });

            });

          }

        }
```

any hint?

Comment: sorry mattunt i having trouble posting code here, i am new here

Comment: Anyone saw this??